# ng-repeat can't be passed as parameter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am writing a custom directive. I have done quite a lot examples on this, passing methods, objects, strings etc. But now I have to pass the ng-repeat's content as parameter and I can't pass it in any way. Details are as follows:

Javascript file of my directive. As seen, it has an fRepeat, which will carry the ng-repeat's content from the outer scope to the directive.

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        fRepeat: '@',
        fClick: '&'
    },
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: '/directives/f-list_jsp'
};
```

My custom directive's layout:

```
<div class="dataTable">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="{{fRepeat}}" ng-click="fClick">
            <div ng-transclude></div>        
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is how I use the directive from any page:

```
<f-list f-repeat="fund in funds track by $index" f-click="fCtrl.showDetails($index)">
    <i class="fa fa-top fColor{{fund.risk}}"></i> {{fund.title}}
</f-list>
```

However I always get the error:

> Expected expression in form of '*item* in *collection*[ track by
>   *id*]' but got 'fRepeat'.

I have tried passing this as:
`fRepeat: '&'` or `fRepeat: '='` in the Javascript file in any case but no use. Isn't it possible to pass it as a string, or isn't it ever possible at all?

Comment: What's the point of `'` in the fRepeat's value? Where does `geRepeat` come from? Please note that `ng-repeat` expects a **fixed** expression and `{{fRepeat}}` is evaluated after `ng-Repeat`, so this cannnot work.

Comment: Like zeroflagL mentioned, your ng-repeat can not receive a dynamic expression. However, I am pretty sure you could pass your `collection` as a parameter and it should work. Would that be an option for you ?

Comment: @zeroflagL that's fRepeat I edited. I have tried all cases, with and without `'`.

Comment: @AdelaN, that was what I thought at first. But the type of collections, the item of the collection to be used, and layout of the rows will always change, so I cannot make that.

Comment: An easy solution would be a `template` function instead of `templateUrl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this ?

```
restrict: 'E',
replace: false,
scope: {
    fRepeat: '@',
    fClick: '&'
},
transclude: true,
link : function(scope, element, attrs, transclude){
    var template = 
'<div class="dataTable">'+
    '<ul class="list-unstyled">'+
        '<li ng-repeat="'+scope.fRepeat+'" ng-click="fClick">'+
            '<div class="f-list-transclude"></div>'      +  
        '</li>'+
    '</ul>'+
'</div>';
     var trancludedContent = transclude(scope.$parent);
     element.html(template);
     var compiledContent = $compile(element.contents())(scope); 
     element.find('f-list-transclude').append(transcludedContent);

}
```

The call would look like to :

```
<f-list f-repeat="{{'fund in funds track by $index'}}" f-click="fCtrl.showDetails($index)">
    <i class="fa fa-top fColor{{fund.risk}}"></i> {{fund.title}}
</f-list>
```

The main difference with your approach : i use a template in memory so i can modify it as much as i want before compiling it with angular (don't forget to add $compile dependency). Note that i don't watch scope.fRepeat, i don't expect it to change as a ng-repeat expression doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried, as you sugeested in your post and was able to get it quite well. Since you haven't mentioned your whole code, so I have assumed something and took some from your post and putted them under the sample demos.

> 1. Refer first [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/d59sp1e0/).

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <f-list f-repeat="{{item}}"></f-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "One"
  }, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Two"
  }, {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Three"
  }, {
    "Id": 4,
    "Name": "Four"
  }, ];
});

app.directive('fList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      fRepeat: '@'
    },
    template: "<p>Hello - {{singleItem.Id}} </p>",
    link: function(scope, ele, attr) {
      scope.singleItem = JSON.parse(scope.fRepeat);
      console.log('sha', scope.fRepeat);
    }
  }
});
```

> 2. Refer second [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/cL720v15/).

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <f-list f-repeat="item"></f-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "One"
  }, {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Two"
  }, {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Three"
  }, {
    "Id": 4,
    "Name": "Four"
  }, ];
});

app.directive('fList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      fRepeat: '='
    },
    template: "<p>Hello - {{fRepeat.Id}} </p>",
    link: function(scope, ele, attr) {
      console.log('sha', scope.fRepeat);
    }
  }
});
```